# How to use 2 Graphic-cards at once

Tags: dual-gpu

So i have a ols 660 stil lieing around i`ve wanted to use it in my curent pc where there
is a 1650 already instaled.
So both of them fit in the motherboard but i can only have one driver installed at once
so is there a posibility to use both of them for like mining or something else?

Comment: Can we ask what's an "ols 660"?

Comment: If your talking about Nvidia hardware that won’t work, since the driver that supports the 1050, doesn’t support the 660. Even if you could, all of your cards, would be very ineffective at mining.